# Convert a toggle switch into a momentary response

Tags: switches, pulse, latch, toggle-switch

I'm working on a project and I need to use a toggle switch to control a device that expects a momentary signal.

What I want is send a momentary pulse when turning it on and off. Ie: swith off to on: positive pulse, switch on to off: positive pulse again.

I've got do this with a small arduino-like board but I'm looking for a pure hardware alternative.

My knowledge of electronics are quite small. I thought about using an inverter (NOT gate) to detect both latches (low and high) in the toggle switch plus a few more components, but I'm not sure how to design it.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Doing this in hardware makes no sense if the switch is wired to the micro-controller input as you can detect a change of state in software. What is the problem with the software approach?

Comment: The switch is not wired to the micro-controller. I did a test with a micro-controller to see if I was capable of solve it.

Comment: Actually, there are two separate system that I want to combine. A controller with some switches plus other features and a machine that expects momentary signals. I want to add a small box between both system to convert the latch signal of the toggle switches to a momentary response without modify any of the two systems.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a schmitt trigger EXOR gate like this: -

[image]

Every time the input waveform changes state you get a positive pulse at the output and the duration of that pulse is determined by the RC time constant.

Comment: It was really simple. Thank you! The schmitt trigger gate is to avoid bouncing problems, right?

Comment: @Garet No, the schmitt trigger is fundamental in turning a rising or falling edge at the input into a positive pulse whose width is determined by R1 and C1.

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for the very same thing, but I cannot find it in any store (i'm guessing there are already premade chips for that ?) Are ther other names to find something like this ?

Comment: Maybe you are looking in the wrong store and need to buy on line from RS, Farnell, Digikey or Mouser.

Comment: Is EXOR similar to XOR ? Or are these two different things ?

Comment: It's the same thing.

Comment: Oh, thanks, that's mainly why I couldn't find it. And many thanks for the shops suggestion !